# ¿Cómo insertar nombre al inves de ID?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo ese codigo que encontre justo aca en stackoverflow.

Lo que hace es insertar los datos del jugador en la base de datos y eso incluye la liga y la division, pero al estar en otra tabla trae el id de la liga y el id de la division.

Hay alguna forma de insertar el nombre de la liga y el nombre de la division al inves del id?

**ARCHIVO PHP**

```
<?php

include('conectar.ini.php');
/*obtenemos los datos del primer select*/
$sql = "select * from liga";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$filas = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Select Ajax</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Liga</label>
    <select id="liga"><!--bandas = liga-->
      <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
      <?php foreach ($filas as $op): //llenar las opciones del primer select ?>
      <option value="<?= $op['id_liga'] ?>"><?= $op['nombre_liga'] ?></option>  
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <br/><br/>
    <label>Division</label>
    <select id="division" disabled="">
     <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
    </select>



    <!-- Agregamos la libreria Jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var division = $('#division');
        $('#liga').change(function(){
          var liga_id = $(this).val();
          if(liga_id !== ''){
            $.ajax({
              data: {liga_id:liga_id},
              dataType: 'html',
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'obtener-division.php'
            }).done(function(data){            
              division.html(data);             
              division.prop('disabled', false);
            });

          }else{ 
            division.val('');
            division.prop('disabled', true);
          }    
        });
      });
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

**ARCHIVO obtener-division**

```
<?php

include('conectar.ini.php');

$liga_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'liga_id'); 

  $sql = "select id_division, division, liga_id from division where liga_id = ".$liga_id;  
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $filas = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
  mysqli_close($conn);

?>


<option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
<?php foreach($filas as $op): //creamos las opciones a partir de los datos obtenidos ?>
<option value="<?= $op['id_division'] ?>"><?= $op['division'] ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Resulta cuando hago el INSERT esta insertando el id de la division y el id de la liga.

¿Hay alguna forma de insertar el nombre de la liga y el nombre de la division al inves del ID?

Comment: Hola, disculpa. ¿Qué es inves?

Comment: @Alfabravo perdon seria al contrario, ose al contrario de indertar el id me gustaria insertar el nombre

Comment: La forma correcta de hacerlo es insertar el id, no el nombre.

Comment: @alanfcm si, entiendo solo que estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar el listado en la datatable, me muestra el id y no el nombre y cuando uso el INNER JOIN ya no funciona la busqusqueda. Hay otra pregunta sobre ese tema que hice esta tarde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, ten en cuenta que guardar textos en vez de los ID te puede causar líos después, cuando cambie el nombre de la liga (ej. que la *Liga Banamex* pase a ser *Liga Santander* o cosas así) y todos los datos que tienen guardado el nombre ya no tienes con qué asociarlos en la lista de ligas.

Dicho ésto, para lograr lo que dices sólo tienes que cambiar el valor que tienen los option en el atributo value, que es lo que se envía cuando haces submit. Es decir

```
<option value="<?= $op['liga'] ?>"><?= $op['nombre_liga'] ?></option>
```

y

```
<option value="<?= $op['division'] ?>"><?= $op['division'] ?></option>
```

Para los select que tienes, y que son los que te decimos que pueden fallar si cambias los nombres, tienes que cambiar la condición porque ya no viaja el ID

```
$sql = "select id_division, division, liga_id from division where nombre_liga = ".$liga_id
```

Comment: Ya hice eso pero al cambiar el id por el nombre ya no me muestra las divisiones, porque son select asociativos una vez que seleccione la liga me muestra otro select con las divisiones

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra Eh, pero si hicieras debug verías cómo tienes que cambiar la consulta del select. Para la próxima no estaría mal que lo intentaras y le contaras a la gente qué te falló. Por ahora, está editada la respuesta

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, gracias a todos

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra si esto resolvió la duda, marca la respuesta como aceptada por favor

Comment: Es que esa no es la respuesta, ya resolvi lo otro asi que eso lo dejo asi como esta. Muchas gracias, igual lo marco

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra Entonces comparte tu respuesta, la idea no es yo ganar rep sino que haya una respuesta que le sirva a otros con la misma duda :)

Comment: La respuesta esta en la otra pregunta, yo por las dudas de no poder solucionar lo otro, opte por cambiar el INSERT